# SSL: Error following the ubuntu.com/server/docs/security-certificates#generating-a-csr

Tags: ssl, openssl

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS with the latest upgrade, on a just installed machine.

I'm following the guide to generate a csr.
Everything has been fine, until I received an error.

The latest command was `sudo openssl ca -in server.csr -config /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`

which returned

```
Using configuration from /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
Enter pass phrase for /etc/ssl/private/cakey.pem:
140578226378048:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:69:fopen('server.csr','r')
140578226378048:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:76:
```

I wasn't able to find any suggestion on the internet.

Comment: *"I'm following the guide to generate a csr"* - there is no THE guide. It is unclear what you are referring too. But the error message clearly says that the file `server.csr` that you explicitly specified with `-in ...`  is not there. This means either the (unknown) guide you are using is wrong or you failed to properly follow the guide - which is unknown too since it is unknown what you did in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever guide you're following is for generating a CSR and signing it with your CA.

In 99% of all cases, that part is not going to be needed.

Instead, you should be referring to the numerous other guides out there (Digital Ocean's guides, etc.) for how to generate a certificate CSR for handing off to a real SSL certificate provider:

```
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
```

That creates the server.csr that you then provide to the certificate authority.  GoDaddy, etc. all need the CSR, not the "CA" commands you were running.